# Usage of word 'Stagnation'

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Can word 'stagnation' mean state of not moving physicaly (by a person)?

English is not my main language and I couldn't find the right answer.

Thanks

Comment: *Stagnation* means "lack of progress or development". The term *stagnant* (meaning unmoving) can be applied to fluids such as air or water, but not to people. You need *inactive* (or one of its [synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/inactive)).

Comment: Stagnate/stagnation are not used to refer to physical movements of people, but only in a figurative sense: ***to stagnate*** to stop developing or making progress: 
 ***I feel I'm stagnating in this job.*** http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/stagnate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use the word '[sedentary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sedentary)' (MW, definition 2) to refer to people and animals.

> doing or requiring much sitting "a sedentary job"
>
> not physically active "a sedentary lifestyle"

So typical usage would be

> My boyfriend is pretty sedentary; I have to fight to get him off the couch on weekends.
>
> House cats sleep for 18 hours a day; but when they are awake, they aren't sedentary at all.

The technical term in biology for a creature that doesn't move at all is '[sessile](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sessile)' (MW definition 2) - although 'sedentary' is used sometimes for that also.

> permanently attached or established : not free to move about "sessile sponges and coral polyps"

When we apply '[stagnant](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stagnant)' (MW definition 2) to people, it's more about their character, their thoughts, or something metaphoric.

> not advancing or developing

So you could say:

> I feel stagnant lately - maybe I should take an art class or go backpacking through Europe.